# Who updated the List/Library Columns

Tags: permissions, governance, sharepoint-fields

This is about governance of SharePoint site.. The owners of the SharePoint site are playing with the site and create tickets when they mess it up.. Worst they are playing with the Production sites..

Example:

There was a rule on a number field with Min = 1 and Max = 6, they changed it to Min = 0.3 and Max = 0.6 and created ticket that entering number 1 in the field isn't working..

I don't want to hear about stopping rights or letting them understand the results of their action.. We are working on it..

For now is there a possibility that I can know who updated the List column? or who made the List changes?

Just like this question, but its not an SPFile in this case, does the SPList object has these properties? [SharePoint 2010 - last modified by who](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74865/sharepoint-2010-last-modified-by-who)

If not, what alternatives do I have?

**UPDATE**

I don't have Central Administration rights on Production server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn on Auditing and look into Audit Log Reports for such events. Following events are available, which can be turned on/off.

•   Opened and downloaded documents, viewed items in lists, or viewed item properties (This event is not available for SharePoint Online sites)
•   Edited items
•   Checked out and checked in items
•   Items that have been moved and copied to other location in the site collection
•   Deleted and restored items
•   **Changes to content types and columns**
•   Search queries
•   Changes to user accounts and permissions
•   Changed audit settings and deleted audit log events
•   Workflow events
•   Custom events

Comment: Okay, I will give it a try and let you know.. thanks for directing..

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps someone has a better answer, but get a copy of the log files (pronto, before they're overwritten), and find out who was visiting:

/FldEdit.aspx?List={listguid}&Field=fieldname

or VldSetng.aspx?List={listguid} for validation settings

(Of course, you may need to visit those pages yourself to get the right guids)

The above is the edit page for the field. Of course, they could have visited the page without changing anything...

Comment: This sounds like one of the solutions, why it didn't came in my mind.. But one problem, there can be so many log files during the time, there are many websites running on production server.. How should I be able to check the timespan? It will be difficult to go through all the logs for the whole day of course

Comment: Use merge-splogfile. It combines the logs from all servers in an output file. It even has parameters for start and end date/time. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607721%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: hmm.. we are still looking.. I will mark answer soon..